# Point Displacement in MapServer

Tags: qgis-3, mapserver, overlapping-features

In QGIS symbology controls there is a "Point Displacment" option for offsetting points that are close visual clarity.  Is there a similar control for MapServer?

Comment: I fear there is not. Perhaps you could use clusters as an alternative https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/cluster.html.

Comment: The cluster function is the opposite of what I need.  I need to decluster!  I suppose the same algorithm could be used as a step to identify points to decluster.

Comment: At least by cluster can show the number of overlapping points in the label but you are right, for the geometries it is doing the opposite to displacement.